# problem mounting exFAT on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mount, exfat

I already installed exfat-fuse and exfat-utils. However using

```
mount -t exfat /dev/sdc1 /media/user/CamStorage/
```

The result shows error:

```
ERROR: failed to read upper case table (5836 bytes starting at cluster 0x3).
```

Any idea how to fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. After the `-t` option, you must specify the FS type, see [`man mount`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html). Either specify the type or leave the `-t` option out.

Comment: Hi sir @Melebius. Sorry i forgot to include the FS type. I already updated my question. Thanks.